# filter a datasource using a multiselect Kendo

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a grid and a multiselect ,i want to filter the grid by the multiselect according to what i select ,and when i de select,the grid should be filterd accordingly,here is my grid:

```
 $("#grid").kendoGrid({                   
                dataSource: ds2,                   
                height: 550,                  
                sortable: true,
                pageable: {
                    refresh: true,
                    pageSizes: true,
                    buttonCount: 5
                },          
                  columns: [
                       { field: "name",
                         title: "Name",width:"50px"},
                       { field: "Description",
                       title: "Description", width: "80px"
                       },
                       { field: "WindSpeed",
                       title: "Wind Speed", width: "40px"
                       },
                       { field: "RPM",
                       title: "RPM", width: "40px"
                       },
                       { field: "Power",
                       title: "Power", width: "40px"
                       }
                      ]
            });
```

the data which bind the datasource:

```
 var ds1 = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                data: rsturn_f.EventNames
            });

   var ds2 = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                data: rsturn_f.Data
            });
```

and here is the multi select:

```
 $("#evnts").kendoMultiSelect({
                placeholder: "Select products...",
                dataTextField: "Nme",
                dataValueField: "Nme",
                //autoBind: false,
                select: onSelect,
                deselect: onDeselect,
                dataSource: ds1

            });
```

by onselect i do this:

```
 function onSelect(e) {

                ds2.filter({ field: "Description", operator: "startswith", value: e.dataItem });
 }
```

now if i want to filter on multiple value and un filter by removing the values from multiselect i dont know what should i do,any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use change event of the Multiselect. You can directly use a function in the operation attribute which is passed to the dataSource filter API.

```
 function onChange(e) {
     ds2.filter({ field: "Description", value: this.value(), 
          operator: function(currentValue, filterValues){
               if(filterValues.length===0){
                  return true;
               }

                   if(filterValues.indexOf(currentValue)!==-1){
                      return true;
                   } 

               return false;
       }
 });
```

}

Comment: I removed the for loop. 
I have made a demo at [link](https://dojo.telerik.com/aMICepUF/2)